# Cookies missing in React but not in Django

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I use SimpleJWT and RestFramework for Authentication. The Tokens are stored in the cookies after login is finished and request is send to the login api which is in React.

```
class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

    try:
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    except TokenError as e:
        raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])
       
      # set access token in browser with Httponly cookie.
    res = Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    access_token = serializer.validated_data['access']
    res.set_cookie("access_token", access_token, max_age=settings.SIMPLE_JWT.get('ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME').total_seconds(),samesite='Lax',secure=False, httponly=True)
    
    return res
```

**Cookies accessed from Django:**

```
print(request.COOKIES)
```

returns:

```
{'userVisitedBefore': 'true', 'tabstyle': 'html-tab', 'csrftoken': 'NECdxoDLb6fszteb8dB11ELh9l2keYUuHM13AaRAxHUHX45GJ9URloJnia9GrqCS', 'sessionid': 'jjafw09sok8wa05756ntjNr6nwxhg6q0', 'access_token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1niJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjM0NTY1ODk0LCJpYXQiOjE2MzQ1NjQ5OTQsImp0aSI6Ijc1ZGY0Njc4MzY1ZDRlNjc5NDM1NTRlMTgzMTU5Nzc1IiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MX0.2Ew92rRIRvoxylpgRu4uGnRGdOuoPV7NSgmGxzS6bnw'}
```

**Cookies accessed from React:**

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
console.log(cookies.getAll([]))
```

returns this **without the access_token and session id**:

```
{userVisitedBefore: 'true', tabstyle: 'html-tab', csrftoken: 'NECdxoDLb6fszteb8dB11ELh9l2keYUuhM13AaRAxHUHX45GJ9URloJnia9GrqCS'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested: My "Solution" was to save the Token in the Cookies via [universal-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie) which were then accessable from both Django Views and the React Frontend. Also instead of saving them via a CustomTokenObtainView, I saved them directly in the React Login Component likes this:

```
axiosInstance
        .post(`api/token/`, {
            email: formData.email,
            password: formData.password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            cookies.set('access_token', localStorage.getItem('access_token'), { path: '/'});
            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =   'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token');
            history.push("");
            location.reload();
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```